# How to run db.runCommand( { cleanupOrphaned: "<database>.<collection>" } ) using python

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have created a python connection object `(db_conn)` that points to primary of my replica set, when I run `db_conn( { cleanupOrphaned: database name.collectionname } )` I get an error saying `NameError: name 'cleanupOrphaned' is not defined`

Comment: Could you please add some context in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all pymongo commands, any unquoted keys will be treated as variables, hence the error message you are getting. You can achieve your task with something like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db =  MongoClient()['admin']

db.command({'cleanupOrphaned': 'mydatabase.mycollection'})
```